# Winbind info shows local users that do not exist

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos, winbind

I am setting up Samba on a Linux machine running CentOS 6 (called localhost, and the AD computer I am connecting to is dc.companyname.com), and I have done everything successfully, except when I type

```
wbinfo -u
```

It shows a local user, **LOCALHOST+[username]** and also a domain user **[username]** below it. Oddly, when I do *cat /etc/passwd*, it doesn't show the local user account...

The problem I have is I want Samba to authenticate against the AD server first before the local user, so I set up /etc/nsswitch.conf as such

```
passwd: winbind files
shadow: winbind files
group: winbind files
```

But I believe that is not the right way to do it? Because I might potentially lock out the root access if there is a "root" user in the Active Directory DC.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? I have also tried deleting the samba cache at /var/lib/samba and restarted the servers, but that **LOCALHOST+[username]** still shows up for some reason...

If I can remove that user, I can do

```
passwd: files winbind, etc
```

which is the right way.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is no root user in AD, the safe way to configure nsswitch is `passwd: files winbind`, we need to see your smb.conf